# Config cloudinary for development and production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, config, cloudinary

In my app on rails I use carrierwave and cloudinary for upload images.

I set config file cloudinary.yml and all work well.

```
development:
  cloud_name: _my_app_name_
  api_key: '_my_cloudinary-key_'
  api_secret: _my_cloudinary_secret_
  enhance_image_tag: true
  static_image_support: false
production:
  cloud_name: _my_app_name_
  api_key: '_my_cloudinary-key_'
  api_secret: _my_cloudinary_secret_
  enhance_image_tag: true
  static_image_support: true
test:
  cloud_name: _my_app_name_
  api_key: '_my_cloudinary-key_'
  api_secret: _my_cloudinary_secret_
  enhance_image_tag: true
  static_image_support: false
```

How can I config cloudinary to use it only for production?

And for development use just local storage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like the following in your uploader:

```
storage :file unless Rails.env == "production"
```